# Timeline in node based compositing

Tags: nuke

I use Natron. What I want to ask about programs like Nuke, Natron, and Fusion is: Are they only for compositing one frame basically? Or can I composite a video? Just for example there is no timeline. That is, I must first fit all the video at one time and then composite? or are there any timeline nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, the workflow goes like this:

1. Capture your plates, real, cg, doesn't matter.
2. Hop into Nuke, composite your plates, then render each shot individually.
3. Edit the shot in your editing-software such as premiere.
4. When the final edit is done, re-import each individually rendered clip into a grading software such as Resolve, apply your color grading, export again and replace the ungraded file in your edit.

So just for pipeline-purposes, it's often inconvenient to use a timeline in compositors like Nuke.